# importing library in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Am trying to run a python script that i downloaded from the internet

```
import os, subprocess, sys, socket, time, struct, random, xml.sax, getopt
import shutil
import Output
import numpy as np 
...
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downtown.py", line 20, in <module>
    import Output
ImportError: No module named Output
```

Am totally new to python , and I want to know whether the missing import is python's or a user library

Comment: What ist this  `Output` module? Did you write it? Did you get it from a third party? How is it installed? What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: what is the name(s) of the file/files you downloaded?

Comment: Make you you have `Output.py` in the same directory as `downtown.py`.

Answer (score 1):

As a first hint, observe the missing module `Output` starts with a capital `O`, which fails to follow [convention of using lowercase-only for module names](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). Therefore `Output` is most certainly a user library. Alternatively, `Output` might be a class that would correctly need to be imported via `from somelib import Output`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard module - it looks like a user module that you should also download from wherever you got the original script.